XRDP sessions issues
I have a Linux SUSE enterprise desktop server which users connect remotely thru XRDP from Windows computer.
At first glance, they can get access, but after a while, the session is freeze or stuck.I need to restart the  server many times.
How  can I fix this issue?
Thank you.

So, what did your investigation show? For how long it even works? Were you attempted to connect again, is that successful? What if you connect over SSH and see what is system doing? Where's logs? Have you tried to only restart the service, not the whole machine? And so on.

Hi.
I only checked the XRDP service and is up and running. I restarted xrdp but is not working properly, sends back the message where sesman is running and then failed to logon.

Fill everything I mentioned into the question please, up to the point another people are able to reproduce your setup. For now, I'd say "no problems for me" and so will say anybody else. How we can help with the problem we can't observe?
